# Access SQLAlchemy relationship before insert

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm instantiating a new SQLAlchemy object that I have no intention of saving to the database.  However, I would like to be able to view it's relationship properties after instantiating it.

```
class Alert(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'alert'
    alert_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    alert_code = Column(CHAR(1), ForeignKey('alert_code_desc.alert_code'))
    alert_description = relationship('AlertCodeDescription')

class AlertCodeDescription (Base):
    __tablename__ = 'alert_code_desc'
    alert_code = Column(CHAR(1), primary_key=True)
    alert_description = Column(String)
```

```
new_alert = Alert(**data)
alert_description = new_alert.alert_description.alert_description  #this causes an error
```

Is there a way to populate the data in the relationships or would I have to query for that data some other way?

Answer (score 0):

This is very similar question to [Can I use SQLAlchemy relationships in ORM event callbacks? Always get None](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28684511/92807), with the same answer.

The relationship doesn't get set by SQLAlchemy automatically when manually creating objects. If you want to access `alert_description` in the event callback, set it when you create the `Alert` instance:

```
ad = AlertCodeDescription(alert_code='A', alert_description='something')
a1 = Alert(alert_code=ad.alert_code)
db.session.add(a1)
db.session.commit()

assert a1.alert_description is None

# Here: set the relationship object, instead of the foreign key
a2 = Alert(alert_description=ad)
db.session.add(a2)
db.session.commit()

assert a2.alert_description == ad
assert a2.alert_code == ad.alert_code
```

Comment: I realize that I could do that, but I was wondering if you could invoke the loading of a relationship without ever saving the data of the first object.  Guess it is not possible.