# Can I use SQLAlchemy relationships in ORM event callbacks? Always get None

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a User model that resembles the following:

```
class User(db.Model):

    id = db.Column(db.BigInteger, primary_key=True)
    account_id = db.Column(db.BigInteger, db.ForeignKey('account.id'))

    account = db.relationship('Account',
         backref=db.backref('ref_users', cascade='delete'))

    ...

def after_user_write(mapper, connection, target):
    target.account.invalidate_cache()

event.listen(User, 'after_insert', after_user_write)
event.listen(User, 'after_update', after_user_write)
event.listen(User, 'after_delete', after_user_write)
```

Upon insert `after_user_write` is being called, but `target.account` is `None` (which causes an error) when I expect it to be an Account model. `target.account_id` is set correctly, it just seems like the relationship reference isn't working as I'd expect.

Any ideas on what's causing this?

Answer (score 3):

The relationship doesn't get set by SQLAlchemy automatically when manually creating objects. If you want to access `account` in the event callback, set it when you create the `User` instance:

```
a1 = Account()
u1 = User(account_id=a1.id)
db.session.add(u1)
db.session.commit()

assert u1.account is None

a2 = Account()
# Here: set the account object, instead of the id
u2 = User(account=a2)
db.session.add(u2)
db.session.commit()

assert u2.account == a2
assert u2.account_id == a2.id
```

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution I've found for this is to use the [Session.enable_relationship_loading()](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Session.enable_relationship_loading) method. Example:

```py
def after_user_write(mapper, connection, target):
    db.session().enable_relationship_loading(target)
    target.account.invalidate_cache()  # Account will no longer be None here
```

Comment: Thanks Peter. This saved the day. Docs read "enable_relationship_loading() exists to serve special use cases and is not recommended for general use" but I didn't find any alternative. And it works.